# Why do Terminal in Rubymine and Iterm2 have different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I installed a rails gem on RubyMine Terminal window.
And then I checked the rails version. But it didn't work.
However, On Iterm2 I can check my rails version.
I already tried `reset`, `restart rubymine`. but it didn't recognize rails.

Why ? :(

```
# Terminal on RubyMine
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

# Iterm2
$ rails -v
Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)
Rails 4.1.12
```

Comment: Are you using the default system ruby or a version manager (such as rbenv or rvm)? Also, are you running this command within the same folder in RubyMine and iterm?

Comment: It's also interesting how it goes if you launch RubyMine from the Terminal

Comment: @Anuj I'm using asdf-vm as version manager. I ran command at same folder.

Comment: I'm not sure but it's solved.
few hours later, I ran the command again and it properly worked.
Thanks everyone!